# Break an integer to single digit bytes in java

Tags: java, arrays

I need to break a large integer into a single digit byte array. Like if the integer is `26051`, the byte array should be:

```
b[0]=2, b[1]=6, b[2]=0, b[3]=5, b[4]=1.
```

I've tried:

```
    int i,j=0;
    byte b[] = new byte[20];
    //read integer i
    while(i>0)
       { b[j]=i%10;
         i=i/10;
         j++
       }
```

But it is giving me errors as expected...
Please suggest me a solution and sorry about my English.

Comment: You have not initialized `b`.

Comment: what is `i` supposed to start at when you start the while loop? `20`?

Comment: Your code is not valid Java code (it won't compile).

Answer (score 2):

You should spend more time on your question before posting it - if the code doesn't compile you should either mention that you have a problem compiling it, or you should fix it before posting.

But it's an interesting question nonetheless. You can do this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // 'i' is the number to process - left code similar to the question
    int i = 26051, j = 0;
    // Allocate as many bytes as needed. The 10-log of the number,
    // rounded up, is the number of digits in the decimal representation.
    byte[] b = new byte[(int) Math.ceil(Math.log10(i))];
    while (i > 0) {
        // Work backwards through the byte array so that the most significant
        // digit ends up first.
        b[b.length - 1 - j] = (byte) (i % 10);
        i = i / 10;
        j++;
    }

    // Print the result
    for (byte x : b) {
        System.out.println(x);
    }
}
```

Comment: I admit your solution is better than mine. +1

Comment: The result is the same :-) You can also use `digits.add(0, next)` to get the list in the right order without the `reverse` call.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this might help you.

```
private static void breakDigits(int i) {
    List<Integer> digits = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    while(i>0){
        Integer next = i % 10;
        i = i/10;
        digits.add(0,next);
    }

    for(Integer element:digits){
        System.out.print(element);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 byte b[]  = new byte[20];
```

should be valid ..